# Error when installing Seaborn with Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I tried to use pip install seaborn but it says Requirement already satisfied......

I installed both python 2.7 and 3.5 and in python 2.7, I have install the seaborn and I tried to install it in 3.5 but it gives me this error.

If I didn't install it in python 3.5, seaborn does not work in python 3.5.

Anyone help?

Comment: Did you do `sudo pip install` or only `pip install`?

Comment: I used pip install in windows cmd.

Comment: OK, I solve it by opening the command window in python 3.5 instead of cmd and use pip to insall the seaborn and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same problem (I'm using Python 3.5 and Ubuntu 15.04).

First I would advice you to uninstall whatever Seaborn installation you might have and then run 'sudo apt-get install python3-seaborn'

Using 'sudo apt-get install seaborn' will do the trick. Please note that you will need to update seaborn afterwards (I got version 0.6).

Running pip3 install (pip3 for Python 3) with the -U command will update Seaborn.
'pip3 install seaborn -U'

Hope it clears the problem for you :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12840795)

Comment: Updated my comment with the content from the link I referred to. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

> sudo pip3 install seaborn

Comment: For Ubuntu, I needed: > sudo pip3 install seaborn

Answer (score 0):

To successfully install seaborn on python3.5 or 3.6 etc.....

```
pip install seaborn
```

Make sure that you have install mandatory dependencies which includes:

- numpy (>= 1.13.3)
- scipy (>= 1.0.1)
- pandas (>= 0.22.0)
- matplotlib (>= 2.1.2)

Follow this [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html) to learn more